# Block outgoing traffic of cluster user

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, cluster

Recently I received an account in a computer cluster. It doesn't have a firewall so any kind communication can happen. However, I would  like to set up a firewall for any outgoing traffic except for ssh in my user scoount (/home/user/).
I'm a complete rookie and the cluster admin didn't gave me any advice (except for: do whatever you want but DO NOT touch anything outside your home).
Is there a way to accomplish this only for my user without being in the sudo list and without messing other users?
Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: No. Speak to your admin.

Comment: I'm not sure the thing you're asking for exists as a concept. Network connections are (broadly speaking) between two processes, and have very little to do with the file/directory system.